# Changing cell style in V10.0.2

Tags: notebooks, version-10

In *Mathematica* 10.0.0 and 10.0.1 I used to change cell style by putting the cursor anywhere in the cell and then invoking one the short cuts (Alt + 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) to change cell style easily.

Now in V10.0.2 this feature is not working and to change the cell I need to select the cell first and then do the short cut.

Can any one suggest what to do to make *Mathematica* 10.0.02 work as it did in 10.0.1,

Comment: Yes it is duplicate. I think this question should be closed.